# How to tell Google Translate to not translate web site if its language is TR

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I use Google Translate as an automatic language translator on my website. My codes are as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'auto',
        autoDisplay: false,
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }

</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I want to add an "if condition" here

I want to tell Google to not auto-translate if my site language is Turkish.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `translate="no"` to an element so , it will not get translated, to skip translation when the language is 'tr'. below I have added a frontend example.

```html
<p id="elemID" > </p>
```

Dynamically add `translate="no"` to the element , if the document language is 'tr'

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event)){
 let lang = document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang");
 if( lang == "tr"){
  let parag = document.queryElement("#elemID");
      parag.addAttribute("translate","no");

 }

}
```